# Convert from Avro to Python using python shells except spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, avro, parquet

Can I convert from avro to python using python shells except spark?

I've searched the blog pages, but all cases are python with spark.

Comment: You could try fastavro: https://github.com/fastavro/fastavro/

Answer (score 0):

With `com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:4.0.0` package you can read  **AVRO** files with **pyspark** like this example:

```
avro_df = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").load("example.avro")
```